# Restrict the components in AEM 5.6.1

Tags: aem

How can I restrict the components in AEM 5.6.1 that can be used in a particular parsys of a template with out selecting them in the design mode?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In CRXDE, under `/etc/designs/[your design]/jcr:content`, you can define nodes to represent each of your templates & their paragraphs & list the allowed components for each.

The format is a node for each template that contains a node for each parsys (both `[nt:unstructured]`).

The parsys node then has a `sling:resourceType` defined of `foundation/components/parsys` and a `components` property of `String[]`. For an example, check out how the Geometrixx one is defined: `http://localhost:4502/crx/de/index.jsp#/etc/designs/geometrixx/jcr%3Acontent/contentpage/par`

You could then extract this via VLT, which gets stored as a `.content.xml` file under `etc/designs/[your design]`.

Alternatively, you can create that file by hand, too. E.g. the following would define 'Your Design' as allowing default "text" and "image" components on the "yourParsys" paragraph of "yourTemplate".

```
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0"     
          xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0"
          xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" 
          xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="cq:Page">
    <jcr:content
      cq:template="/libs/wcm/core/templates/designpage"
      jcr:primaryType="cq:PageContent"
      jcr:title="You Design">
        <yourTemplate jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <yourParsys
              jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
              sling:resourceType="foundation/components/parsys"
              components="[foundation/components/text,foundation/components/image]"/>
        </yourTemplate>
    </jcr:content> 
</jcr:root>
```

---

This allows you to move this file across instances (e.g when deploying a CRX package) so that you don't have to configure environments individually & which components are allowed where can also be managed by version control.

Comment: is there a way to limit how many components can be dropped into `yourParsys`? For example I want one and only one `foundation/components/text` to be droppable into it and nothing else.

Comment: No straightforward way that I've found. You might be able to overlay a JS file within the sidekick & do a check on insert? Or embed the component directly in the template with a check box to show/hide. To be honest though, these are the type of things that are more easily solved by editorial guidelines than development effort.

Comment: @Behrang There is, but it requires either overriding the default parsys component OR implementing a request filter to delete excess nodes.  The right way to handle that will really depend on the core business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the allowed parents property for the component to restrict where a component is used e.g., `allowedParents="[*/parsys]"`

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do this is to create a new parsys component that simply extends the existing one with sling:resourceSuperType. Then use allowedParents property on the component and specify your specific parsys.  Finally use your specific parsys on the page template in question. I have not tried this as of yet, but have kept the idea in my back pocket. Let me know if it works.