# Components Checked in Design, But Not Displaying in Sidekick

Tags: aem

We're running Adobe CQ, Version 5.5.0.20120220 Service Pack 2, and I've been tasked with creating some new templates and restricting the components available to those templates without having to manually configure them in design mode. I've followed the advice of the top-voted answer from [Restrict the components in AEM 5.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275062/restrict-the-components-in-aem-5-6-1). We already had this .content.xml file under our design node, so I simply copied an existing section from the file that is working fine and modified to match my new template.

The problem I'm having is that when I create a new page with the new template, the sidekick is empty. I can see in CRXDE that my configuration is live on the server. I can also see the configured components as checked when I go into design mode. But the sidekick remains empty. If I uncheck a component and re-check it, stuff will start showing up in the sidekick. I've done this and exported the design node via package manager, and the resulting file matches exactly (except whitespace) what I'm deploying from source control. Is there some gotcha that I'm missing here? Our other templates that are configured this way show the specified components in the sidekick just fine, so I'm guessing the difference lies in my template or the resourceType specified by my template, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Edit -- Added snippet from .content.xml. The whole file is a bit long. If it's helpful, I can link to the full file instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Page">
    <clientlibs/>
    <jcr:content
        cq:doctype="html_5"
        cq:lastModified="{Date}2013-05-08T14:25:15.588-04:00"
        cq:lastModifiedBy="admin"
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        jcr:title="My Site"
        sling:resourceType="wcm/core/components/designer">
        <department-resources-main jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <par
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="foundation/components/parsys"
                components="[/apps/aau-42/components/components/lms-user-media]">
            </par>
        </department-resources-main>
    </jcr:content>
    <images/>
</jcr:root>
```

Template data, located at /apps/aau-42/templates/department-resources-main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:description="Template for AAU Main Department Resources Pages"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Template"
    allowedParents="[/apps/aau-42/templates/department]"
    jcr:title="AAU Main Department Resources Page">
    <jcr:content
        cq:allowedTemplates="[/apps/aau-42/templates/department_resources_detail]"
        jcr:primaryType="cq:PageContent"
        sling:resourceType="aau-42/components/pages/department-resources-main" />
</jcr:root>
```

Page component data, located at /apps/aau-42/components/pages/department-resources-main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:description="Main Department Resources Page"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="Main Department Resources Page"
    sling:resourceSuperType="aau-42/components/pages/base"/>
```

Comment: Can you post your .content.xml for reference?

Comment: Could you double-check that there are no JS errors when the page loads (e.g. via the console) & try the page in a fresh browser (to make sure the JS driving the Sidekick isn't caching)

Comment: Oh brother...I fired up the page in a Chrome incognito window, and lo and behold that worked. That's extremely frustrating. Thanks for the suggestion @anotherdave.

Comment: @DavidHosier NP, it's happened to me quite often :)

Comment: For reference there are many more suggestions in http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone seeing this in the future, see the comment from @anotherdave. Cached stuff has bitten me before; I should have known. As a general rule, if something you think should be working is not working in CQ, ALWAYS clear cache or try in a fresh browser!

Comment: Did you find the solution for this ?

Comment: Some troubleshooting:

1. Kindly make sure that your components jcr:title is not the same as the component's name. For Eg: if the name of the component is text, then the title should at least be Text and not text. Change it and then check in the design mode, it will list your component group.

2.If your component does not have dialog then child node cq:editConfig enables the component to show in the sidekick.