# CQ5 hide component on other sites

Tags: aem

Is it possible to hide component on separate sites on CQ5?

Currently they can be managed in `Sidekick` and `Design dialog`. I need to make them to be hidden/available in `Sidekick` and `Design dialog` so content creator will not be able to enable it.

E.g.

Site 1

- Component 1 (shown, selectable)

Site 2

- Component 1 (disabled, can't turn it on in `Design dialog`)

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, are you talking about components in sidekick?

Comment: Yes. I have fixed description :)

Comment: Design Dialog is the way to go, you just need to set a different design on each site then the settings are stored for each design. With access control you can prevent authors from using the design dialog.

Comment: @Thomas as I see the question, the main point is to prevent authors from enabling some components in design dialog.

Comment: The goal is to prevent authors from enabling/using component which are not intended to be on particular sites.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict the components in AEM 5.6.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275062/restrict-the-components-in-aem-5-6-1)

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas suggested, for each site you should create separate `design`, where you can set allowed components in `parsys`. To prevent author from enabling them:

- First option:

  - for each site you create separate `groups` and assign `authors` to this groups (so site1 author is in group g1 and site2 author in group g2)
  - for group g1 you allow access rights for component 1
  - for group g2 you deny access rights for component 1
  - then authors from group g2 will not see component 1 in `Design dialog`
- Second option (**I don't recommend to do this**):

  - you can override widget `/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/form/ComponentSelector.js` where in constructor you can remove/disable some specific components/groups depending on current location in `Design dialog`