# Component may be added only to a specific page(in specific parsys)

Tags: aem

I have homepage(has parsys) and contentpage(has parsys). I have a SimpleTextComponent component. I want to this component be used only in page contentpage(only in contentpage parsys). How can I do that? 
(It is also advisable not to show a component in the Sidekick for other pages, only contentpage.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this in Design Mode.  When you edit the template that is used for your contentpage, you can change the parsys on that template to allow the use of your SimpleTextComponent.  You govern which components are available on a template-by-template basis, so as long as other pages use different templates you will be able to configure those templates differently.

[This article](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/author/page-authoring/default-components/designmode.html) outlines how to use Design mode to set which components are available.  [This page](https://myprogressivelearning.wordpress.com/2014/10/15/how-to-add-components-to-the-sidekick-in-cq5-adobe-aem/comment-page-1/) has a tutorial.

Also see [Restrict the components in AEM 5.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275062/restrict-the-components-in-aem-5-6-1).

Comment: Thank you! You helped me with the 2nd part of the question. Sorry that first raised the question not correctly. Now I have corrected it. If you know the answer to 1st part of the question, please help me. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me--I only see 1 question here.  Can you clarify?