# How to restrict a component to appear in a specific path (or specific website) only

Tags: components, aem

How to restrict a component to appear in a specific path (or specific website) only?

Here is the dialog.xml definition:

```
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0"
    xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="My Custom Component"
    allowedParents="[*/parsys]"
    allowedPaths="/content/[a-z0-9]{2,5}/[a-z]{2}(_[a-zA-Z]{2})?(/.*)?"
    componentGroup="Grundfos-Responsive"
/>
```

My goal is to be able to add the component under the path

```
/content/racs/....
```

only. Take note that `/content/racs/...` is a relative path to our website.

I tried this one:

```
allowedPaths="/content/racs/[a-z]{2}(_[a-zA-Z]{2})?(/.*)?"
```

but it did not work.

I also tried the `allowedParents`

```
allowedParents="/content/racs/[*/parsys]"
```

but it also did not work.

I want to add the component under this path only:

```
/content/racs/....
```

Comment: let us know if you found solution to this problem. I also have similar requirement

Answer (score 0):

First of all, component definition is in **.content.xml** and not in **dialog.xml**.

Second - You **can not** restrict component placement in similar way as we can restrict **template**. From [this link](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/components.html#Properties%20and%20Child%20Nodes%20of%20a%20Component) you can make sure, that component does not have such properties.

Third - what we can do, is to restrict component appearence in SideKick using Disign Mode. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23288117/1675951) to see details of this approach. Some extracts from that answer:

> In CRXDE, under `/etc/designs/[your design]/jcr:content`, you can define nodes to represent each of your templates & their paragraphs & list the allowed components for each.

...

> The parsys node then has a sling:resourceType defined of foundation/components/parsys and a components property of String[]. For an example, check out how the Geometrixx one is defined: http://localhost:4502/crx/de/index.jsp#/etc/designs/geometrixx/jcr%3Acontent/contentpage/par

Also [there](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/page-authoring/default-components/designmode.html#Enable/Disable%20Components%20-%20Classic%20UI) you can check how to do it via UI.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but for your third answer, it did not restrict the component to be visible in other sites. It is visible and can be dragged to a parsys in /content/racs/... and can also be added to /content/site2.... and to /content/site3/.. and so on.

Comment: @Racs, do you sites have the same design?

Comment: yes the sites have the same design. The component should appear only under the path /content/site1... it should not be visible or should not be able to add it to a parsys in /content/site2.. and so one. Thanks

Comment: @Racs, From what I see - the only way is to customize SideKick, but it's not recommended. I would suggest to change disign, so each site has unique one.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this for restrict a component to appear in a specific site :

```
  allowedPaths="[/content/racs(/.*)?]"
```